# Select all options with a given data-id in a form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a form, and I'm trying to disable or hide options in a select form element which have a particular data-id attribute.  Example form:

```
<fieldset id="fuu">
    <select name="bar1">
        <option value="option1" data-id="available">Option 1</option>
        <option value="option2" data-id="notAvailable">Option 2</option>
        <option value="option3" data-id="available">Option 3</option>
    </select>

    <select name="bar2">
        <option value="anotherOption1" data-id="available">Option 1</option>
        <option value="anotherOption2" data-id="notAvailable">Option 2</option>
        <option value="anotherOption3" data-id="available">Option 3</option>
    </select>
</fieldset>
```

I would like to hide (and disable for browsers which don't support hiding) the options with data-id of "notAvailable".

Here is what I've tried:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        //hide unavailable options
        var unavailable = notAvailable;
        $('#fuu select option').each(function (event) {
            if ($(this).attr("data-id") !== unavailable) {
                $(this).hide().prop('disabled', true);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

My selector seems to fail, because when I the below code to log the result, I get "notAvailable : undefined" 127 times (one for each option in my form)

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        //test by logging
        var unavailable = notAvailable;
        $('#fuu select option').each(function (event) {
            if ($(this).attr("data-id") !== unavailable) {
                var loggedID = $(this).attr("data-id");
                console.log(unavailable + " : " + loggedID);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: give quotes to var unavailable = "notAvailable";

Comment: notAvailable , notAvailable are string literals so use them as string and qoute them. ex : 'notAvailable' , 'notAvailable'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try following code:

```
$("#fuu select option[data-id='notAvailable']").hide().prop('disabled', true);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This :

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('select option').each(function(){
   
    if($(this).attr('data-id')=='notAvailable'){
      $(this).prop('disabled',true);
    }
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<fieldset id="fuu">

<select name="bar1">
<option value="option1" data-id="available">Option 1</option>
<option value="option2" data-id="notAvailable">Option 2</option>
<option value="option3" data-id="available">Option 3</option>
<select>

<select name="bar2">
<option value="anotherOption1" data-id="available">Option 1</option>
<option value="anotherOption2" data-id="notAvailable">Option 2</option>
<option value="anotherOption3" data-id="available">Option 3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thank you, this solution does work perfectly, and I appreciate the working example.  I chose the answer by Hanif because it uses less code, and for what I'm ultimately doing (creating a toggle to show/hide "notAvailable", his approach is cleaner.  I upvoted your answer because it does work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

1. Provide this under quotes `var unavailable = "notAvailable";`
2. Change the condition as `$(this).attr("data-id") == unavailable`

**Example:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  //hide unavailable options
  var unavailable = "notAvailable";
  $('#fuu select option').each(function(event) {
    if ($(this).attr("data-id") == unavailable) {
      $(this).hide().prop('disabled', true);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<fieldset id="fuu">
    <select name="bar1">
        <option value="option1" data-id="available">Option 1</option>
        <option value="option2" data-id="notAvailable">Option 2</option>
        <option value="option3" data-id="available">Option 3</option>
    </select>
    <select name="bar2">
        <option value="anotherOption1" data-id="available">Option 1</option>
        <option value="anotherOption2" data-id="notAvailable">Option 2</option>
        <option value="anotherOption3" data-id="available">Option 3</option>
    </select>
</fieldset>
```